# deep find() query in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so my schema looks like something like this

```
var PagesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        citiesList:{
            country:String,
            city:String
        }
});
```

i want to access citiesList in my route so i tried

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){


    Pages.find({"citiesList"}, function(err,citiesList){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.render('landing',{citiesList:citiesList});
    }
});
});
```

but it's not working any advice please ?

Answer (score 1):

That query is searching for any document that look like `{citiesList: "citiesList"}`. If you want *all* "citiesList", you can instead use `{}` to find all documents, and a projection to limit it to the `citiesList` field: `Pages.find({}, "citiesList", cb)`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

If instead you want only those subdocuments in a formatted list, you can use an [aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) to process them